# Structure of a malloc block

Tags: memory, malloc

Reading [here](http://prog21.dadgum.com/179.html) it says malloc can't allocate less than 32 bytes. I have also seen somewhere saying 16 bytes is the minimum.

This diagram shows generally what malloc block looks like, but is not detailed enough.

[image]

The first link suggests there is an 8-byte minimum required to store the *size* of the block. Piecing these things together, my guess is:

- 16 bytes for the size (this, but that would limit block size to 65,535 bytes)
- 16 bytes for the pointer to the next free block (but that would also limit the number of blocks to 65,535 ~ 4 GB, which I guess makes sense).

That would mean the block structure would be:

```
[size, pointer, userdata....]
[16b, 16b, 65,535b max]
```

This would mean malloc can't allocate less than 16 + 16 + 16 = 48 bytes.

Wondering if this is accurate or if there is more to it.